# Progress dialog wot'n show

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-dialog, android-progressbar

I have this adapter and I'm trying to display progress dialog when media player is preparing. But for some reason my dialog wont show. Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong? Also I don't get any logCat error output.

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class AlbumDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private static ArrayList<Songs> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ImageView playSong;
    private Albums album;
    private ImageLoader loader;
    private int oldPosition = -1;
    private DatabaseHelper helper;
    private ImageView downloadSong;
    private boolean exists;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public AlbumDetailsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Songs> products,
            Albums album) {
        activity = a;
        this.album = album;
        loader = new ImageLoader(activity);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        data = products;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_items, parent, false);

        ImageView songthums = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.song_item_thumb);
        TextView singer = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.songs_item_album_singer);
        TextView songNumber = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.songs_item_number);
        TextView albumTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.songs_item_album_title);
        TextView feat = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_feat);
        feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
        if (data.get(position).getFeat().length() <= 1) {
            feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        singer.setText(data.get(position).getSONG_ARTIST());
        loader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).getSONG_THUMB(), songthums);

        helper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        helper.openDB();
        playSong = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_play);
        downloadSong = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_download);
        if (helper.getDownloadedSong(album.getTAG_ID(), data.get(position)
                .getSONG_TITLE())) {
            Log.v("--", "Y");
            downloadSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_no);
        } else
            downloadSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_yes);
        helper.closeDB();
        if (data.get(position).getSONG_MP3().length() > 0) {
            if (!data.get(position).getIsPlaying())
                playSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_nr);
            else
                playSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
        } else
            playSong.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_pr);

        downloadSong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!helper.isDBOpen()) {
                    helper.openDB();
                }

                if (helper.isSongShared(data.get(position).getSONG_TITLE()
                        .toString().replace("'", ""), album.getTAG_ID())) {

                    if (helper.getDownloadedSong(album.getTAG_ID(),
                            data.get(position).getSONG_TITLE())) {

                        Toast.makeText(activity,
                                R.string.song_already_downloaded,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {

                    shareAlbum(data.get(position).getSONG_TITLE(),
                            album.getTAG_ID(), position);
                }

                helper.closeDB();
            }
        });

        playSong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // final ProgressDialog bufferingDialog = new
            // ProgressDialog(activity);
            final ProgressDialog bufferingDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    activity);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        ((AlbumDetails) activity).changePicToPlay(position);
                        if (oldPosition != position) {
                            bufferingDialog.setMessage(activity
                                    .getString(R.string.buffering));
                            bufferingDialog.show();
                            ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                    .changePicToPlay(oldPosition);

                            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                            try {


                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(data.get(position)
                                        .getSONG_MP3());

                                mediaPlayer.prepare();

                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                postData(1, position);

                                // on complete
                                mediaPlayer
                                        .setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompletion(
                                                    MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                                ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                                        .changePicToPlay(position);
                                            }
                                        });
                                bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                        Log.v("--", "padna menuvam vo stop");
                                        ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                                .changePicToPlay(position);
                                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                                        bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(activity,
                                                "Song not existing",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        /*
                         * if (bufferingDialog.isShowing())
                         * bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                         */
                        // mediaPlayer.release();
                        Log.v("--", "played before1");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    if (data.get(position).getIsPlaying()) {

                        Log.v("--", "played before0");
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                                                        Log.v("--", "sviri smeni vo stop");
                                ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                        .changePicToPlay(position);
                                if (bufferingDialog.isShowing())
                                    bufferingDialog.dismiss();

                    } else {
                        Log.v("--", "not played before");
                        bufferingDialog.setMessage(activity
                                .getString(R.string.buffering));
                        bufferingDialog.show();
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(data.get(position)
                                    .getSONG_MP3());
                            ((AlbumDetails) activity).changePicToPlay(position);
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();

                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            postData(1, position);
                            // on complete
                            mediaPlayer
                                    .setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                                            ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                                    .changePicToPlay(position);
                                        }
                                    });
                            bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (IOException e) {


                                    Log.v("--", "padna menuvam vo stop");
                                    ((AlbumDetails) activity)
                                            .changePicToPlay(position);
                                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                                    Toast.makeText(activity,
                                            "Song not existing",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    bufferingDialog.dismiss();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }

                oldPosition = position;
            }
        });

        ImageView youtube = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_video);
        if (data.get(position).getSONG_MP4().length() > 0) {
            youtube.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_nr);
            youtube.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    postData(2, position);
                    Intent intent;
                    if (!data.get(position).getSONG_MP4().startsWith("http://")) {
                        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse("http://"
                                        + data.get(position).getSONG_MP4()));

                    } else {

                        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data
                                .get(position).getSONG_MP4()));
                    }
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        albumTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getSONG_TITLE()));
        singer.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getSONG_ARTIST()));
        // songNumber.setText(position + 1 + "");
        songNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        helper.closeDB();
        return vi;
    }

    private void shareAlbum(final String songId, final String albumID,
            final int position) {

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                            ShareOnFacebook.class);

                    i.putExtra("songs", data.get(position));
                    i.putExtra("album", album);
                    i.putExtra("position", position);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                    if (!helper.isDBOpen())
                        helper.openDB();
                    if (helper == null) {
                        helper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
                        helper.openDB();
                    }
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        ((AlbumDetails) activity).changePicToPlay(position);
                    }
                    helper.addSharedSong(songId, albumID);
                    helper.closeDB();

                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(
                activity.getString(R.string.do_you_want_to_share_this_song_on_facebook_))
                .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.yes),
                        dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.no),
                        dialogClickListener).show();
    }

    public void exists(boolean b) {
        exists = b;
    }

    public void toastMsg() {
        Toast.makeText(activity,
                activity.getString(R.string.song_not_available),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public boolean getExists() {
        return exists;
    }

    public boolean isSongAvailable(final int position) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(data
                            .get(position).getSONG_MP3()).openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    exists(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    exists(true);
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                if (getExists() == false) {
                    toastMsg();
                }

            };

        }.execute();

        return getExists();
    }

    public static void postData(final int choice, final int position) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://nelu.burduja.com/musica/counting_song.php");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            2);
                    switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "song_streaming", "1"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("song_id",
                                data.get(position).getSONG_ID()));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("song_video",
                                "1"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("song_id",
                                data.get(position).getSONG_ID()));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "song_download", "1"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("song_id",
                                data.get(position).getSONG_ID()));
                        break;
                    }

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return null;
            }

        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: related to the one you asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671930/android-dialog-wont-show?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, but here more code is added, and deleted that question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 hours of searching and looking at my code I finally got the answer... I need to put the `dialog.dismiss()` in my mediaPlayer's `setOnPreparedListener`